# Error when trying to use Azure Key Vault task in pipeline. No package found

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I try to create my first CI/CD pipe with azure devops. My build, test and publish tasks works fine, but I have problem with fetching secrets from azure key vault:

```
##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\1\s\**\*.zip
```

In my Azure Key Vault I had one secret named "testVault". I would like to print it in log console to check whether it works or not. This is my whole yaml file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

--TEST TASK SKIPPED

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output 
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'BudgetAppARMServiceConnection'
    WebAppName: 'HomeBudgetApp'

- script: echo $(testVault)
  displayName: 'testvault'
```

Unfortunately i received error:

```
Got connection details for Azure App Service:'HomeBudgetApp'
##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: 
d:\a\1\s\**\*.zip
Successfully updated deployment History at
```

Comment: I can not find the Azure Key Vault task in pipeline mentioned above. Did you skip it?When you want to access the secret, you need to ensure the Azure service connection has at least Get and List permissions on the vault. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops).

Comment: it has permissions. Connection Error had been solved before. This task does not work
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'BudgetAppARMServiceConnection'
    WebAppName: 'HomeBudgetApp'

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems not about the Azure Key Vault. It is caused in task AzureRmWebAppDeployment.If you are using "Azure App Service Deploy" task, set the "Package or folder" path with your actual path which contians the app service contents generated by MSBuild or a compressed zip or war file. Please ensure the file or folder exists.

[image]

BTW, it's useful to turn on debug mode for your pipeline, define a variable  `system.debug` with value `true`. You will get the detail log info when the job runs.